# PHP if statement, variable not displaying

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, field, echo

I have the following code:

```
<?php if(the_field('required_libraries') ) { echo 'Title' . $required_libraries; } ?>
```

The field does exist and it displays correctly. However, the 'Title' text does not.

This works for me where there aren't any variables, so I don't quite understand why it isn't working here.

Comment: It should work fine as long as the `if` statement is getting executed

Comment: What does `the_field` returns? And in the case it does return something, what will be its interpretation as boolean?

Comment: @Nicolás nothing is falsy in PHP

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa are you telling me that `0`, among others, is not falsy?? Then what about [boolean casting](http://cl.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) ?

Comment: I'm using code supplied, no matter how I change it, it still won't display. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/code-examples/

Comment: This worked, thanks for downranking my first post without explaining why:

    <?php if(get_field('required_libraries')){ ?>
       <p><strong>Aditional requirements:</strong> <?php the_field('required_libraries'); ?></p>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: @Nicolás :-P nope I tell you that nothing as in empty string or `null` for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You might need to use isset in your if statement.

```
<?php

    if (isset($required_libraries)) {
        echo 'Title' . $required_libraries;
    }

?>
```

Can you post what your "the_field" function does?

Update

Per the documentation you provided, it looks like you should use get_field() in the if statement (not the_field()).

```
<?php

    if(get_field('required_libraries')) {
        echo 'Title ' . get_field('required_libraries');
    }

?>
```

It looks like the_field() echos the field value, so you could also do this:

```
<?php

    if(get_field('required_libraries')) {
        echo 'Title ';
        the_field('required_libraries');
    }

?>
```

Comment: It retrieves a custom field and displays it: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/code-examples/

Comment: I updated my answer with new examples. It looks like you need to use get_field in the if statement. Use get_field to get the field value. Use the_field as a shortcut to echo the value.